# Как сделать два WHERE в sqlite3?

Tags: python, android, sqlite, sqlite3, pydroid

Как сделать два WHERE на sqlite3?
Вот пример:
У нас есть таблица **files**
В ней три столбца **name**, **premium**, **id**
И там есть три линии:
1.**Outfile** **Yes** **10**
2.**Outfile2** **No** **20**
3.**Outfile3** **Yes** **30**
Далее пользователь может забрать и выдать премиум команде:

```
def premium_edit(yes_or_no=None):
    if yes_or_no is None:
        print("Ошибка, укажите забрать или выдать премиум файлу")
    elif yes_or_no == "yes":
        cursor.execute("UPDATE files SET premium = {} WHERE name = outfile ".format(yes))
        print("Успешно")
    elif yes_or_no == "yes":
        cursor.execute("UPDATE files SET premium = {} WHERE name = outfile ".format(no))
        print("Успешно")
```

И вот следующий код, где нам нужно проверить:

```
def get_id():
    id = cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM files WHERE name = outfile, premium = yes")
    print(id)
```

Comment: `WHERE name = outfile AND premium = yes` - не?

Comment: Вроде бы да работает!